# Jquery Multiple load in a DIV

Tags: jquery, html, load

Here is my code:

```
$('#right').load('textes.html #nicolas');
$('#right').load('textes.html #antoine');
```

The problem is that the content of the `div` antoine overwrites  the content loaded by the div nicolas in the right `div`

```
div #right : load div nicolas from file textes.html = ok
div #right : load div antoine from file textes.html = overwrite content = No!
```

I'd like to append antoine to nicolas. This is to add nicolas and then add antoine so `#right` will be nicolas + antoine

I have tried to get the content into a var but it didn't work.

Any idea ?

---

On top of that... I would like to add a rule `<hr>` BETWEEN each load

---

Maybe something like this, but this doesn't work.

```
$('#right').load('textes.shtml #nicolas').append('<hr>').load('textes.shtml #antoine'); return false;
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something but it seems like you all have been missing the fact that this is an ajax call and you are calling functions procedurally and not as a callback function based on a successful ajax response.

Besides, if you are doing anything more complex than loading some (X)HTML into an element, you should probably use one of the more powerful jQuery ajax methods (i.e., get() or post() or ajax()).

Assuming you'll get (X)HTML in the response:

```
// Only ONE ajax call and very simply parsing... 
$.get('textes.html', {}, function(data) {
    var $response = $('<div />').html(data);
    var $nicolas = $response.find('#nicolas')
    var $antoine = $response.find('#antoine');
    $('#right').append($nicolas).append($antoine);
},'html');
```

It's really as simple as that.

Comment: plus one on this all these years later... just came across a situation where I needed to update multiple divs after an ajax form post... this solution worked great with a little tweaking to fit my usage.

Comment: Found this code very useful, thank you! I have a question regarding it, lets say I have a div inside "#nicolas" and I need it to be removed on this very get call, how can I do this? @KyleFarris

Answer (score 8):

WHy not load them both in one call:

```
$('#right').load('textes.html #nicolas,#antoine');
```

**EDIT**
Inspired by Justice way I thought of the follwoing:

```
var $page = $('<div />').load('textes.html #nicolas,#antoine');
var $nicolas = $page.find('#nicolas');
var $antoine = $page.find('#antoine');
$('#right')
 .html($nicolas)
 .append('<hr/>')
 .append($antoine);
```

This will make only one (or two, depending on what firefox feels like) calls to the server. Thus saving bandwidth. But it also gives you more freedom in how to insert the elements and in which order.

Comment: you are really smart !... it look way to simple... but what about the <hr>

Comment: something bizzare append... $('#right').load('textes.html #a, #b, #c, #d, #e'); the content in the #right div is NOT in the right order. it look like a,b,e,d,c or anything else !

Comment: look by yourself, maybe i have done something wrong
http://tac-o-tak.ca/getm-comediens.html
http://tac-o-tak.ca/textes.shtml

Answer (score 4):

Here's the full source code for a solution.

I've hosted a working sample on JSBin.com: http://jsbin.com/ulodu (Editable via http://jsbin.com/ulodu/edit)

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js"></script>
<title>Sandbox</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script>
$(function(){
  $.get(
    'http://jsbin.com/oyuho',
    function(response){
      /* 
        Wrap the response in a <div /> so that we can use
        find() instead of filter(). Also remove <script> tags.
        This is essentially what $.load() does.
      */  
      var responseWrapper = $('<div />').append(response.replace(/<script(.|\s)*?\/script>/g, ""))
      $('#content')
        .append(responseWrapper.find('#nicolas'))
        .append('<hr />')
        .append(responseWrapper.find('#antoine'));
    }
  );
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It look really complicated to me, maybe when i will have time, i check that out, but KyleFarris solution look really nice to me, and IT WORK FINE, thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
var nicolas = $('<div />').load('textes.html #nicolas');
var antoine = $('<div />').load('textes.html #antoine');
$('#right')
    .append(nicolas.children())
    .append('<hr />')
    .append(antoine.children())
;
```

Or, Pim Jager's way.

Comment: is it possible to do the load without the extra div markup... just the plain text

and on to of that... i will like to add a rule BETWEEN each load

Comment: The div is there to be a container for whatever is being loaded. The div is dynamically created but is not injected into the page. If you're thinking of doing something fancy, I would do it the way I showed here. Also, I edited this to show how to inject a <hr /> in between the two loaded content sections.

Comment: I like it to work, but got that error : Access to restricted URI denied" code: "1012

i think it dont have anything to do with the code, it something about the load

Comment: This is a better way then mine because it gives you more freedom. However in the worst case scenario it would make four calls to the server.

Answer (score 0):

See the [appendTo](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/appendTo#selector) function.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with the REALLY SIMPLE answer of KyleFarris

I even simplified it a little more, and it work fine

Thnaks everyone, here is the final code :

```
<script>
$.get('textes.shtml', {}, function(data) {
    var $response = $('<div />').html(data);
    $('#right')
    .append($response.find('#nicolas'))
    .append('<hr />')
    .append($response.find('#antoine'));
},'html');
</script>
```