# Yajra datatable is interupting jQuery auto refresh function

Tags: jquery, laravel, yajra-datatable

I have made alert system for new order. For that I am refreshing div (in header) in every three seconds using jQuery function like this

```
setInterval(function() {  
    $("#notification-rf1").load(location.href + " #notification-rf1");
    $("#notification-rf2").load(location.href + " #notification-rf2");
    $("#notification-rf3").load(location.href + " #notification-rf3");
}, 3000);
```

This is working fine on other pages but giving issue on those pages where I am using yajra datatable.

When it refresh after three seconds, then those divs which refreshes (using jQuery in 3 sec) become empty. Means all html inside those divs disappears.

I did some testing and found, if I remove yajra datable's code from controller file then issue get resolves.

Here is the controller code:

```
 if ($request->ajax()) {
    $data = blog_category::get();
    return Datatables::of($data)
    ->addIndexColumn()
    ->addColumn('action', function($row){
    $category = "'".$row->category."'";
    $data = '<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" onclick="return editblogcategory('.$row->id.','.$category.');" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#editcategory"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Delete" onclick="return deleteblogcategory('.$row->id.')"><i class="fa fa-trash font-14"></i></button>';

    return $data;
    })
    ->rawColumns(['action'])
    ->make(true);
}
```

Any solution?

Comment: use seperate method/route for your datatables results.

`$request->ajax()` will be triggered by `$("#notification-rf1").load(location.href + " #notification-rf1");` since it's an ajax call too. Or you can add another condition specifically linked to Yajra datatable calls

Comment: Also, you should check this question, you are requesting 3 times the same page to fill those 3 doms. You can do it with only one request https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866284/jquery-multiple-load-in-a-div

Comment: @N69S `Or you can add another condition`, Hi, I don't know how would I do that. what condition I need for it. Can you show in your answer. I am not much expert. Please elaborate your solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use seperate method/route for your datatables results.

`$request->ajax()` will be triggered by `$("#notification-rf1").load(location.href + " #notification-rf1");` since it's an ajax call too

If you want the janky solution and add another condition to differentiate between yajra calls and other ajax calls, you can use the input `draw` for example which is sent in every request by yajra.

```
if ($request->ajax() && $request->draw) {
    $data = blog_category::get();
    ...
}
```